# Xamarin Forms WebView header cutting off with bottom blank space in iOS 10 alone

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, ios10

My Xamarin.Forms app contains UIWebView which is working perfectly across all platforms except iOS 10. In iOS 10 header is cutting off with bottom blank space.

It happened for my site, hence tried with Xamarin website, same result.

Is it bug in Xamarin?

**Bottom White Space:**

[image]

**HeaderCut** (I scrolled and made it appear little bit)

[image]

Comment: I wish to attach image, but it is not showing here, anybody know why? imgur is blocked here, it could be because of that?

Comment: Did you try WKWebView instead UIWebView.

Comment: I heard about it, but I want to fix it in Xamrin.Forms only, it is working in Android and less than iOS 10 devices

Comment: In Apple documentation they mention use WKWebView instead UIWebView after ios 8.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware, but it is working fine in iOS 9 versions, in iOS 10 only it is behaving like this. Also I am not developing in native, developing Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, issue was with Xamarin.Forms package, my app was using old Forms version 1.3.3, I updated to 2.3 and its working fine now.